# Python Pandas : how to add values in column group by a particular row and put the result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
p_id    b_id      val
101     201       99
101     202       2 
101     203       11
102     201       1
102     202       50
102     203       23
```

I need to add the values in the column `val`, based on `p_id` and `b_id`, to get this result `dataframe`:

ie, for each `p_id`:

sum1 = val(201) + val(202) = 99 + 2 = 101

sum2 = val(201) + val(203) = 99 + 11 = 110

```
p_id   sum_1     sum_2
101    101        110
102     51         24
```

The resultant `dataframe` should look like this
I tried running this

```
df2 = df.groupby(['p_id', 'b_id'])['val'].sum().reset_index()
```

but not being able to get all the rows for each `p_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we are doing `sum` first with `transform`, then `cumcount` create the key, and pivot

```
df.val += df.groupby('p_id')['val'].transform('first')
df['key'] = df.groupby(['p_id']).cumcount().astype('str').radd('Sum_')
df = df.pivot(index= 'p_id', columns = 'key', values = 'val').drop(['Sum_0'],axis=1).reset_index()
Out[228]: 
key  p_id  Sum_1  Sum_2
0     101    101    110
1     102     51     24
```

Comment: But i am trying to add values at index 0, 1 as sum1 and index 0,2 as sum2. So the first row of the resultant `dataframe` should be 101,101,110.